# How to change color of navigationBar & BarButtonItem with scroll

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I want to change the background color of UINavigationBar and the UIBarButtonItem inside this NavigationBar **smothly** while I scroll down the TableView. I saw this in the AirBNB app and have no idea how to do somthing like this. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` and make sure that your tableView/CollectionView delegate is set to the current ViewController.
2. Implement `scrollViewDidScroll(:)` method.
3. Decide your preferred offset to change NavigationBarColor.
4. If you offset condition is met then change your NavigationBarColor.

**SUMMARY**

```
Class UIViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
       if offset > 1 { // Or choose any desired offset
           // TODO:- Change your color for offset greater than 1
       }else {

             // TODO: - Change your nav bar for offset less than 1
       }
   }

}
```